# Which IoC continer to use in cross-platform (Xamarin) applications?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, xamarin, inversion-of-control

I'm building a cross-platform application for Windows, OSX, iOS, Windows Mobile, Android and web in ASP.NET. For every client I use C# (I'm using Xamarin). Everything in single VS solution. My core code (domain) is in **Class Library (portable)**, so it can be used in every UI (Client).

I want to use IoC container in that project and here is my problem:
I don't know whether IoC that I'll pick, will work in every Client. I know that for example *Ninject* doesn't work in portable Class Library - there is *Ninject.Portable* for such project. That made me thinking, it's possible that IoC which I will pick will not work in one of my Clients which will be bad.

So, my question is: **Which IoC containers can be used in portable class libraries and in every client (UI) made in Visual Studio 2015?**

I was interested in **Simple Injector**, but now I have these doubts.

Comment: Why don't you test it? at the end of the day, you have to test your applications on all the clients that you want to support.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Right now I've only WinForms. I've never done ASP.NET or any mobile app. I'm doing it one by one (it's a project just to learn all those technologies).

Comment: Since your libraries should not have a dependency on any library, you can pick different DI libraries for different client applications, and your phone applications will probably even be simple enough that you don't need a DI library AT all. All they will do anyway is send messages to the server. Most complexity will be in on the server.

Comment: @Steven I want to use IoC for my client applications because there will be few similar applications (games) for each UI (operating system). Card games to be exact. So, only for WinForms, there will be 3 different card games. Very similar, so I want to share as much code as possible. So there will be project named "Domain.CardGame", as a core game (shared code - interfaces + default implementations) and additional project (CardGame.Game1) which I will inject. I'm not sure I explained it well. I will post my idea in code review soon

Comment: It's great that you are trying to apply Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection, but those are just patterns; they can ne applied without tooling.

Comment: @Steven tooling, so IoC container? I know that. That's what I'm doing now. Trying to find one that will suits my needs

Comment: @ToddEnglewood the point steven is trying to make is that you should not conflate the principles of IoC  and dependency inversion with the tooling that exists to facilitate them. You can apply the priciples  without using a container, and actually Mark Seeman who wrote the  book Dependency Injection in .net says that he rarely uses IoC containers anymore, just applies the principles and uses what he is terming ['Pure DI'](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)

Comment: @SamHolder Hmm.. by "applying the principles" I thought of preparing code to use on of IoC containers. I've head of Poor's man DI, but as Mark said it sounds "poor". Pure DI is much better name, so I'll have to study this subject for a while to see if this is my choice

Comment: @SamHolder The only thing that bothers me, this project was supposed to be the project where I will learn about one of those IoC containers :)

Comment: Xamarin comes in with a built-in Service Locator called [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/).  Unfortunately it's so absurdly basic it's not suitable for unit-testing _(eg. you can't register your own instances)_.  Fortunately if you use Xamarin Forms Labs, it comes with its own simple Service Locator called [`SimpleContainer`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/IOC) which is unit-testable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have written a small abstraction layer on IoC containers and plugins for containers that work with Xamarin. They are available on NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xlabs.ioc

Tested containers ([unit tests are in GitHub](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/UnitTesting/IocTests)):

- Autofac
- Ninject
- SimpleInjector
- TinyIOC
- Unity

Matt Whetton has written an excellent [guide on how to use them](http://www.codenutz.com/autofac-ninject-tinyioc-unity-with-xamarin-forms-labs-xlabs/).

Comment: I`ve just checked regarding "Ninject" for Xamarin - max version supported for portable libraries is 2.1.0.76

Comment: did updates stop? pre releases are waiting...

Comment: There have not been any changes to IoC in a while. I will need to separate them from the mainstream NuGet release script.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IoC container which works with Xamarin called SystemDot. [It's on nuget.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SystemDotIoc/)

Comment: Autofac and Simple Injector work on Xamarin as well.