# Xamarin Native Dependency Service

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am a little bit new to xamarin , i've made some project with Xamarin.forms and i used a lot the DependecyService.
But now i have a project that we need to make native specefic views so we are not using xamarin.forms, but as i know our PCL code still can be the same, so if i have some methods that require specific platform implementation i can use the dependency service.

As an example , i have a method that require to save in the phone path ,this method is in the PCL, but for the path i need it from Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS.

Can anyone explain to me how do i shall proceed ?
Thanks

Comment: i am not using xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

The simplest without Dependency Injection is create an interface in your PCL. Then create concrete class that implement the interface in UI project. After that initialize and store the instance of the interface in some singleton instance in PCL.

If you want to use Dependency Injection, there is many library available for you to use too. You can refer to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722085/which-ioc-continer-to-use-in-cross-platform-xamarin-applications) where there is an abstraction layer on some major IoC containers.

I have use [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) directly from NuGet in my Xamarin native project too. It is working quite well.

Comment: have an example of that?